# Courses - GPU HPC

Tags: gpu, hpc

My school is offering both GPU and HPC in Spring. I am confused which one to take. From an industry perspective, pls someone tell me which way to go.

Thanks,
Supraja J

Comment: Probably better asked at programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what these courses offer.

Assuming the HPC course covers some parallel programming models like MPI, PGAS, OpenMP, etc..
and that the GPU course covers CUDA and OpenCL.. I would take the HPC course first. Familiarizing yourself with one of the standard parallel programming models first will definitely help in understanding the GPU programming models such as CUDA, which need some prerequisite understanding of the SMPD (Single Program Multiple Data) model of parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

I would take both. If I was forced to choose I would go the HPC route since it would probably be more generic.